# Universal persistent connection pool proxy with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

The issue I have is there are literally 100 different remote servers that keep changing. I connect to these with PHP using curl, that PHP process dies after completion and there's no way to keep the connection open. With my current knowledge I would have to set up each and every one in nginx configuration. The following works for one server:

```
upstream some-server {
    server some-server.com:443;
    keepalive 20;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some-server.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://some-server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

The only issue there is that in the upstream, `some-server.com` is hard-coded and can't be a variable.

The following is my attempt at making a universal version of the same. It does proxy correctly but won't keep a persistent connection pool to the remote server:

```
server {
    listen 8889;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://$http_host$request_uri;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
upstream https-proxy {
    server localhost:8889;
    keepalive 20;
}
server {
    listen 8891;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://https-proxy;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

My guess is that the persistent connection is pooled between my servers running on port `8891` and `8889` which is pointless.

Is it possible to make nginx proxy and pool persistent connections to anywhere? If not, making such a proxy seems trivial. So perhaps a better solution already exists that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You guessed the reason why it doesn't work as intended right. You are trying to use Nginx as a forward proxy and even though it is possible the way you did it, there are many limitations as Nginx is not designed to be used that way.
You should use Squid or even Apache mod_proxy which has better support for forward proxying.

BUT:

Have you tried using $http_host variable in the upstream definition, where the *keepalive* directive is? I'm almost certain it won't work, but let me know :)

Comment: Variables can't be used in the upstream definition. Never heard of Squid before, this needs investigation.